# How to hide section in a Chart.js Pie Chart

Tags: chart.js, hidden, pie-chart

In Chart.js you can hide a section of a chart by clicking on the label on top.
[image]
*picture of a pie chart with hidden section*

I want a section of the chart to be hidden on startup. With another type of chart I would use the dataset hidden property, but pie chart sections do not correspond with the datasets. So if you do the same the entire dataset is hidden, not just the needed section.

(Extra information: I use a pie chart with multiple datasets)

The closest I have come to a solution is this code:

```js
for (i = 0, ilen = (chart.data.datasets || []).length; i < ilen; ++i) {
  meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(i);
  meta.data[index].hidden = !meta.data[index].hidden;
}

chart.update();
```

Or I could overwrite the generateLabels function.

Can anyone help me find a better solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may see an implementation as a plugin [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eaqe6p5u/) and below.

```js
// A plugin that hides slices, given their indices, across all datasets.
var hideSlicesPlugin = {
  afterInit: function(chartInstance) {
    // If `hiddenSlices` has been set.
    if (chartInstance.config.data.hiddenSlices !== undefined) {
      // Iterate all datasets.
      for (var i = 0; i < chartInstance.data.datasets.length; ++i) {
        // Iterate all indices of slices to be hidden.
        chartInstance.config.data.hiddenSlices.forEach(function(index) {
          // Hide this slice for this dataset.
          chartInstance.getDatasetMeta(i).data[index].hidden = true;
        });
      }
      chartInstance.update();
    }
  }
};

Chart.pluginService.register(hideSlicesPlugin);

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [15, 1, 1, 1, 45, 1],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      data: [5, 1, 25, 10, 5, 1],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }],
    // Hide the second (index = 1) and the fourth (index = 3) slice.
    hiddenSlices: [1, 3]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

The slices to be hidden are provided using the `hiddenSlices` attribute, which should be an array of indices corresponding to existing slices. The slices are hidden across all datasets using the `hideSlicesPlugin`, *if* `hiddenSlices` has been set.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with Chart.js 2.7.2. Is there an updated version of this plugin? I can't find it's source.

Comment: See MangaD's answer for a solution in version 3

Answer (score 4):

After creating the chart, you can retrieve its metadata through [`.getDatasetMeta(index)`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#getdatasetmetaindex), change the `hidden` attribute of the desired slice and update the chart as shown in the following code snippet. When the user clicks on the label of the hidden slice, it will become visible again.

```js
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [100, 100, 200, 300, 140],
      backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Colors - Sample Pie Chart'
    }
  }
});

chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[4].hidden = true;    
chart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="150"> </canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers provided here have worked for Chart.js version 3.2.1 (what I am using). Here is what I came up with (and it works):

```js
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

window.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [100, 100, 200, 300, 140],
      backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
      hoverOffset: 6,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: { padding: 10 },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Colors - Sample Pie Chart'
      }
    }
  }
});

toggleData('red');

window.chart.render();

function toggleData(txt) {

    let ci = window.chart;
    let legendItems = ci.legend.legendItems;
    let index;
    for (index = 0; index < legendItems.length; ++index) {
        let legendItem = legendItems[index];
        if (legendItem.text.toLowerCase() === txt.toLowerCase()) {
            // let visible = chart.getDataVisibility(index);
            ci.toggleDataVisibility(index);
            ci.update();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
/*
Note: Do not style the canvas element. See:
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/9089
*/
#myChartContainer {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myChartContainer">
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.2.1/dist/chart.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-uVEHWRIr846/vAdLJeybWxjPNStREzOlqLMXjW/Saeo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

References:

- https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#toggledatavisibility-index
- https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#custom-on-click-actions

Answer (score 2):

## Update - 17/Nov/2019

Don't do this, at the time I wrote this I was new to ChartJS and Web Development as well and it seems that the solution above already outdated, so I tried to answer with things that works for me. Maybe it's already outdated too, I haven't used ChartJS much since then. I moved to Echarts.

---

Since @xnakos answer is already outdated, I just wanted to share the same thing can be done easier in the current ChartJS version (2.7.3). Simply set the values to `undefined`, setting it to other values such as `null` will leave the legends being seen (or not crossed).

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myDoughnut").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Green", "Blue"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, undefined],
      // Set this value to undefined
      backgroundColor: [
        '#f87979',
        '#79f879',
        '#7979f8'
      ],
      borderWidth: 5
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: null
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        borderWidth: 5,
        borderColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 8,
        // color: 0,
        font: {
          weight: "bold"
        },
        backgroundColor: "lightgray"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div width="400">
    <canvas id="myDoughnut"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.4.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>

<!-- Made in 21 Nov 2018 -->
<!-- with ChartJS 2.7.3 -->
```

Here's a link to JSFiddle, for you to play around.
http://jsfiddle.net/irfandyjip89/fokbgnvz/5/

However, must be noted, if you're using datasets on Pie/Doughnut, it's better to set it into `null`. Because one `undefined` value in any of the dataset will cross the legends.

***But if you do*** set one `undefined` values on any of the dataset, it will result in the legends being crossed (or strikethrough). **EVEN WHEN THERE'S A VALUE ON THE NEXT DATASET.**

This means that if you only use one dataset, and you don't want the data being shown in the chart and getting the legends crossed you want to set the values to `undefined`. Whereas, `null` values will get you same result *without* the legends being crossed.

However it's preference on how the Chart should appear, but personally I would want to use `undefined` values if I would like to cross the legends (usually on one dataset chart)and hide the data, and will use `null` values if I would like to just hide the data without getting the legends crossed (usually on multiple dataset chart).

If you want to check how it went when playing with multiple datasets, you can check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/irfandyjip89/fokbgnvz/19/

**P.S.** If you're wondering how did I put a label value on the center, it's using a plugin called [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels)

Comment: This solution works, however all the undefined legends and data become permanently uninteractive and cannot be toggled anymore.

Comment: 但標籤本身該有的功能就失去了，我期望的是他包含所有的資料，而只是先被點選暫時的不顯示。

Comment: This breaks the usefulness of the legend to begin with (showing/hiding on click). Not a good solution, at all.

Answer (score 2):

In V3 of chartjs you can use the API they provide to toggle the visibility of an item.

```
chart.toggleDataVisibility(2); // toggles the item in all datasets, at index 2
chart.update(); // chart now renders with item hidden
```

Note: Only doughnut / pie, polar area, and bar use this.